# Sum of total tokens in array

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document as below - 
            {
                   "array" : [ "Aone" , "Btwo" , "Aone" ] 
            }

I need to aggregate the sum of number of elements in array using aggregation.
value_count is giving me the unique tokens , but that is not what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make array a multi field with a new field called numOfTokens . Declare this field as token count.

You can find more about it here -http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#token_count

This will create  an addition field called array.numOfTokens per document that will have the number of tokens for that field.

Next you can do a simple sum aggregation on that field using - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation